# How to add an event listener in a flexcard to store the selected values in a variable?

Tags: vlocity, omnistudio

I have a flexcard as shown in the image. There is a picklist and I want to store the selected value in some variable/JSON. Would be great help if someone gives their insight on how to record these on-click events into a JSON. I am only able to see the updated value inside the flexcard. For backend work, I need this changed value to be stored somewhere.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.